# wordpress Theme Development style by external css

Tags: wordpress-theming

There are any differant among Them

get_template_directory_uri(); and get_stylesheet_uri(); or, get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **get_template_directory_uri();** 
   = Directory of your current (parent) theme without trailing slash at the end.
   Example: xyz/wp-content/themes/yourthemename
2. **get_stylesheet_uri()** 
   = Returns your style.css path from your current active theme. It is the same than no1 but with /style.css at the end.
   Example: xyz/wp-content/themes/yourthemename/style.css
3. **get_stylesheet_directory_uri();** 
   = Returns your style.css directory as URL. It MIGHT be the same than No1. But No3 referes to the style.css directory of your parent OR, if in use, CHILD Theme. While No1 always returns your parent theme´s style.css directory
   Example: xyz/wp-content/themes/yourthemename/childtheme